# Submitting Open Graph action for approval - submit link not active

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

99% sure my app is set up correctly, it requests the publish_actions permission and I can publish the action using the Open Test user as it states I must do, however when I go to review status my submit link isn't active and it just tells me I need to publish the action using the test user......which i've done. Going around in circles here, what am I missing? Or can anyone recommend a decent guide I can follow as the docs aren't helping me too much.

[image]

Comment: Did you create the Open graph action once?

Comment: I've done it via my app and via the sample code supplied by FB.

Comment: Also, just tried it live and it works on my personal account as well.

Comment: Did you get this message on mouse over: http://i7.minus.com/jbisfMT3lZlv0Q.PNG ?

Comment: OK. But after i created an object of that, i will be able to send it to a review. In the past i had some problems and i tested my source with the Testing Tool: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug Maybe this will help you.

Comment: Hmmm, it seems to be working now. I haven't changed anything so can only assume there is some delay between publishing the action to the test user and the submit button becoming active. Thanks for your help @Mindbreaker

Comment: @RyanBerry, how long time did you have to wait to be able submit it for approval?

Comment: I think once I got over the slight confusion over the process and submitted my action using the test user it was around 1-2 hours.

Comment: It's around 2 hours now since I have the same problem. Any idea why it could happen? I'm pretty sure I have everything set up in my Facebook App properly but the 'Submit' link is still inactive.

Comment: Give it another 24hrs, then if you still have trouble let me know and i'll see if I can help further.